# PyCharm - Jupyter Notebooks - DLL Load failed : The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have recently started using PyCharm (Pycharm 2020.1.1) for all things Python, and followed the instructions give here : 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#get-started

However, I am still getting the following error while trying to run any cell in the Jupyter notebook on PyCharm. I even tried running an empty cell to see if it was an issue with any libraries I was importing, however, it stilll throws the same error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 158, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 301, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 248, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 474, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 435, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "c:\users\viraj\pycharmprojects\orion-constellation\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What could be the possible cause and the solution for this ?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're trying to run ? It will probably help the debug process.

Comment: How did you create the interpreter specified in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with 'pyzmq'

Do the following

1. pip uninstall pyzmq (u might get permission denied, kindly ignore it.)
2. pip install pyzmq
3. Click on "register this interpreter as jupyter kernel" (prompt by pycharm).

This worked for me, hopefully works for you too. :)